# How do you get specific words from a text file?

Tags: c++

Lets say im given a txt file of first names and i want to pull all the names that are of length 5 out. I then want to pick one of the names and randomize"mixup" those letters in that one name. Should i make a vector of strings and use a for loop?

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
for(int i = 0; i < txtFile.size(); i++)
if(txtFile.size() == 5) {
...
```

Comment: Please add more context / details / code such as `txtFile` (What is it?), sample file format that you want to read, along with the code that you've already tried and are stuck.

Comment: IMHO, a `std::vector<std::string>` is sufficient and would make implementation easy. If `length` is defined at compile time, a `std::vector<std::array<char, 6>>` (1 extra `char` for `\0` terminator) could do as well: [Live Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e87dd892f1b25a67). However, is it necessary to store the words at all? You could process each individual word inside the loop which is reading from file.